# Хероку не работает с базой данных. Python Discord bot на базе данных Sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite, discord, heroku, discord.py

Всем привет. Делаю Discord бота с базой данных sqlite3 на Python через библиотеку discord.py, и возникла проблема после загрузки его на heroku. Бот работает ровно сутки, после чего хероку пересоздает бд, тем самым теряя весь прогресс. Возможно ли это как то исправить? Если нет, то подскажите пожалуйста другой хостинг для дискорд бота

Answer (score 0):

Heroku не хранит файлы, если вы их изменяете. Вы можете использовать postgresql, как бд, в том же heroku